# QWidget for Image

Tags: qt, qt5, qwidget, pyqt5, qgridlayout

I am trying to create a simple `QGridLayout` of images in PyQt5 but have found myself stuck because `QGridLayout` only has functionality for adding widgets and layouts via `.addWidget()` and `.addLayout()`.

Below is my code that expects a `QWidget` but is having problems because I can't seem to find any `QWidgets` that can handle a png/jpg file.

```
class myGrid(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)

        # Create Layout
        self.lay = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.lay)

        i1 = QIcon("imgs/img1.png")
        i2 = QIcon("imgs/img2.png")
        i3 = QIcon("imgs/img3.png")
        i4 = QIcon("imgs/img4.png")

        # Add Images to Layout
        self.lay.addWidget(i1, 0, 0)    # Error because type(i1) != QWidget
```

The above is just the first of the images that I would like to add to my layout. The only problem is that because `QIcon` is not technically a `QWidget` I receive a compiler error.

I looked at other `QObjects` that handle images, including `QImage` and `QPainter` but because these classes are all of type `QtGui` I can't pass them into my grid.

Any suggestions for how to produce a `QWidget` from an image or using a specific `QWidget` that handle's images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

QLabel is the widget you need. It can display a QPixmap, not only text.

Comment: Small problem, I was using these `QIcon's` to be placed into `QListWidgetItem's`. Is there a `QWidget` better than `QListWidget` for adding a list of images to a layout?